# Html loaded via ajax is not working with jQuery events

Tags: ajax, html, jquery

I've this code in a file called checkout.tpl, also have a Javascript code and I'll comment below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        $("#checkout").hide();
        $('#payment-address .checkout-content').html(html);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

As you can see here I load some HTML content using AJAX. This is the [HTML content](http://pastie.org/7645865) I'm loading. Notice the input with **id=button-payment-address**. So in checkout.tpl I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#button-payment-address').on('click',function() {
    alert("Click");
    // here goes some code   
});
```

When I click the input with **id=button-payment-address** a alert with "Click" should appear or not? Well is not showed and code is never executed, no errors are trigger so I don't know what's wrong. I test with this other code to and the same result:

```
$('#button-payment-address').click(function() {
    alert("Click");
    // here goes some code   
});

// This seems to be not working with latest jQuery and generates a error
$('#button-payment-address').live('click', function() {
    alert("Click");
    // here goes some code   
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried binding the .on('click') to a higher DOM object? Such as: $('body').on('click','#button-payment-address',function(){});

Comment: @Reynier: In regards to `live`, that has been removed in jQuery 1.9. If you are working with legacy code use the [**migration js**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) which contains those removed features and in addition writes warnings to the debugging console when a removed feature is being used. Great for updating legacy code. See this post from the jQuery guys for the full [**upgrade guide**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Nice, I learn something new today, thanks guys just don't know why or what is wrong in my code, I always does as I said but apparently something change in jQuery

Comment: @Reynier: No worries, jQuery 1.9 was a dramatic change alright compared to any previous releases. Adding to the confusion, jQuery has 2 development streams, jquery 2.0+ is developed and released along-side 1.9. While at the same time jQuery 1.9+ is continued as well. Difference being 2.0 does not support IE6, 7 or 8. More info on that if you are interested in the latest jQuery blog post: [**jQuery 2.0 Beta 3 Released**](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/09/jquery-2-0-beta-3-released/) Have fun :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl good, I'll test soon, now I include the library and warnings aren't showed, I also write this `console.log(jQuery.migrateWarnings);` but still not showing even when I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$('#payment-address').on('click','#button-payment-address',function() {
    alert("Click");
    // here goes some code   
});
```

Comment: +1, In addition for OP's benefit, When using `on` with delegation use the closest static parent element. `document` will work off course but if I read the code correctly so would `$('#payment-address .checkout-content').on('click', '#button-payment-address')` or what ever other parent is the closest static one.

Comment: @mohammad-adil ok, now it works but I'm totally lost, see I have all the jQuery code inside of `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#button-payment-address').live('click', function() {
    alert("Click");
    // here goes some code   
}); });` then what's wrong in my code?

Comment: @Reynier: I also added a note in regards to `live` to your original question.